# Put on hold and rephrasing the question

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question

OK - so I rephrase the [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/285415/) to highlight the physics content as suggested and... zilch. It still stays on hold.
So the only option appears to be to re-post the revised question under a different heading.

Is that how this is supposed to work or should the person who put it on hold actually check on it to see if it was re-edited?

Answer (score 2):

After a question is put on hold and edited, it gets put into a queue to be reviewed for reopening. If enough reviewers think the question is suitable for the site after the edit, the hold will be removed. Otherwise, it stays on hold.

In this case, [the review](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/148926) has been completed, and the reviewers do not believe the changes make the question on topic, so unless there are further edits, the hold will stay.

You should not repost a question on hold to give it another chance. Doing so is considered (a mild form of) abuse of the site.

Comment: The [review for this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/148926) has been concluded - it has three Leave Closed votes and is not in the queue any more. Additional Reopen votes will put it back in the queue, though.

Comment: I will wait until tomorrow. If it is still closed I am unsubbing from the site. It's getting to be seriously negative for me in terms input-output. I also seriously dislike the bias against engineering and experimentalists, and people who cannot tell the difference between the two.

Comment: If the review has already been completed, nothing is likely to change by tomorrow. You can still wait if you want but I don't expect it will make a difference.

Comment: The moderators here are quick to hold and hardly ever remove them.

Comment: @Jiminion Yes, because when a hold needs to be removed, that is typically done by the community. No need for the moderators to get involved.

Comment: I wasn't aware I could unhold something.

Comment: [It takes 3000 reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Answer (score 2):

Well, I tried to play the game and join in (hence my 10,100 points) but this forum is almost totally useless for anyone doing experimental physics. I particularly dislike the snobbish attitude of some moderators who cannot tell the difference between experimental physics and that stinking low class "engineering" stuff.

Last straw as my question on laser-metal interactions being put on hold and not re-opened. After much googling (in scholar) and elsewhere I discovered the answer I sought. And guess what - it's physics. Clue - plasma frequency v wavelength of light.

The output I get from here is vastly less than the time I have put in, and I have a paying job being a real physicist (and engineer - but let's not mention that)

So, I am unsubbing and won't be back.

Dirk Bruere